# Как после цикла foreaech вывести только один раз строку(с условием)

Tags: php, foreach, циклы

Циклом перебираю значения хочу чтобы если значение равнялось то выводило тест а если нет то ошибку. Но но выводит о ошибку много раз!

```
<?php
    $allow_items=array("256","257","258","261","267","268","269","270","271","272","273","274","276","277","278","279","283","284","285","286");
    $id = "256";
    foreach($allow_items as $itm){
        if($id==$itm){
            echo "Success!";
        }else{
            echo "Error!";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Результат:

```
Success!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!Error!
```

Comment: какой тест оно должно выводить? если вы хотите чтобы цикл останавливался как только он найдет число и выводило значение воспользуйтесь break; Если нет, то внятно сформулируйте ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для остановки цикла есть оператор `break`. Для пропуска текущей итерации - `continue`. Если нужно в цикле полностью завершить выполнение скрипта, можно использовать языковую конструкцию `die()`. Примеры:

```
// break
foreach ($allow_items as $itm) {
    if ($id != $itm) {
        echo 'Error!';
        break;
    }

    echo 'Success!';
}

// continue
foreach ($allow_items as $itm) {
    if ($id != $itm) {
        continue;
    }

    echo 'Success!';
}

// die()
foreach ($allow_items as $itm) {
    if ($id == $itm) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        die('Error!');
    }
}
```

---

Но для решения подобной задачи не обязательно использовать циклы - можно воспользоваться подходящими функциями, и получить компактное решение:

```
echo in_array($id, $allow_items) ? 'Success!' : 'Error!';
```